# How do I copy a tab's title in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to copy the title of a web page (or what appears within the tab, the part always visible) and paste that text somewhere.

How can I do this in Chrome?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet):

`javascript:window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",document.title);`

Credit for this `window.prompt` trick goes to [Jarek Milewski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript/6055620#6055620).  This bookmarklet also works in ANY browser, even Netscape 3, and not just Chrome.

Comment: that's a great idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm supposed to do...  Your talking about "bookmarklets"?

Comment: @wizlog: Yes bookmarklets. The above link gives [step-by-step instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet#Installation). Try dragging [Copy Webpage Title](javascript:window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",document.title);) to your bookmarks bar.

Comment: @wizlog: Sorry, superuser does not support draggable bookmarklet links.

Comment: Better version of this answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/659377/42048)

Comment: Cool, I just selected the code and dragged text on Firefox's bookmarks bar. A charm!

Comment: To use the bookmarklet, while on the page of which the title you want to copy, just click on the bookmarklet. (It took me some time to figure this out.)

Answer (score 25):

Add a bookmark by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or clicking on the star on the right end of the address bar.

Copy title.

Click on "Remove".

Comment: Over the address bar or on the right hand side of the address bar?

Comment: Clever hack! This answer is great because it gives the title instantly without reloading the page or searching through source code.

Comment: You can also do this with keyboard only: `ctrl+D` (bookmark), `ctrl+C` (copy), `tab tab tab space` (remove).

Comment: Unfortunately, [Google broke this](https://old.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/17p85md/bookmark_added_workflow_update_infuriating/) 

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved through the page source code:

1. Right click on the page and select 'View Source'
2. Look for the <title> tag
3. Select and copy the text.

[image: view source on a page in Chrome]

Comment: Assuming I understood your question correctly...

Comment: You did... is there a shortcut though?

Comment: View Source keyboard shortcut is: CTRL+U

Comment: Note: this will require to load the web page again, so if it's a complex web page on a slow server, you may have to wait a long time for the source to load. Also, on complex pages, you may have to search past pages of `<meta>` and scripts to find `<title>`. This answer is much faster: https://superuser.com/questions/332717/how-do-i-copy-a-tabs-title-in-chrome/997386#997386

Answer (score 9):

The above script has the annoying habit of creating a blank page with the title at the top, in plain text, making you have to go back to the page whose title you wanted to copy. At least in Firefox 24.0.

A far more effective script that keeps you on the page is:

```
javascript:var%20title=document.title;if(title){var%20re=/(\\|\/|:|\*|\?|\%22|<|>|\|)/gi;title=title.replace(re,'');void(prompt('Page%20Title',%20title));}
```

Comment: Here is the version that also adds the original url after line break:
`javascript:var title=document.title;if(title){var re=/(\\|\/|:|\*|\?|\"|<|>|\|)/gi;title=title.replace(re,'') + "\r\n" + document.location;void(prompt('Page Title', title));}`

Comment: ... or just click Cancel on the dialog from above script instead of Ok, and it won't create such an extra page (tested on Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It looks like this script removes "|" and ":" from the page titles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Google Chrome extension [Copy URL + Title](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url-%20-title/dgagjmdgbakclelfacghmmbadkdegjjh?hl=en):

Features:

- Copy Page URL
- Copy Page Title
- Copy Page HTML Link
- Copy Page Title and URL
- Copy URL of all Tab
- Copy Title of all Tab
- Copy HTML Link of all Tab
- Copy Title and URL of all Tab

Also available for Opera from https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/copy-url-title/

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is any such extension out there that does not record browsing history.

Answer (score 2):

This bookmarklet copies the page Title to the clipboard with a single click.

```
javascript:copyToClipboard = str => {
const el = document.createElement('textarea'); 
el.value = str; 
el.setAttribute('readonly', ''); 
el.style.position = 'absolute'; 
el.style.left = '-9999px'; 
document.body.appendChild(el); 
const selected = document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) : false; 
el.select(); 
document.execCommand('copy'); 
document.body.removeChild(el); 
if (selected) {
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); 
document.getSelection().addRange(selected); 
} 
};
copyToClipboard(document.title);
```

Answer (score 2):

**This bookmarklet copies the title to the clipboard:**

```
javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.title);
```

**Browser compatibility:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText#browser_compatibility

**How to create a bookmarklet**

1. Bookmark any web page (e.g. this page) and save it to the Bookmarks Bar (in Chrome) or Bookmarks Toolbar (in Firefox) or Favoutires (in Safari).
2. Right click on the new bookmark and choose **Edit Bookmark**.
3. Change the **Name** to something meaningful, e.g. "Copy Title"
4. In the **URL** copy and paste the JavaScript: `javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.title);`
5. Click on **Save**
6. Now when you click on the bookmarklet it will copy the title into the clipboard.
7. Paste into the destination document or app

Answer (score 1):

An answer inspired by SΛLVΘ's answer, although not identical:

Bookmark that page.

In the list of bookmarks, right click on that bookmark, choose Edit, and you will see the name and the url; by default,  the name is the tab's title, unless you modify it

Answer (score 1):

If you need Markdown as the end result, use Chromium Extension [Copy Tab Info](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-tab-info/lppcgkhgnfalmlnhkjgdfmkhhgdilfdd).

[image: SCREENSHOT]

## Features

### Active tab in current window

- Copy title of active tab in current window as string
- Copy URL of active tab in current window as string
- Copy link of active tab in current window as HTML
- Copy link of active tab in current window as Markdown
- Copy link of active tab in current window as Markdown ordered list item
- Copy link of active tab in current window as Markdown unordered list item

### All tabs in current window

- Copy titles of all tabs in current window as text
- Copy URLs of all tabs in current window as text
- Copy links of all tabs in current window as HTML ordered list
- Copy links of all tabs in current window as HTML unordered list
- Copy links of all tabs in current window as Markdown ordered list
- Copy links of all tabs in current window as Markdown unordered list

### All tabs in all windows

- Copy titles of all tabs in all windows as text
- Copy URLs of all tabs in all windows as text
- Copy links of all tabs in all windows as HTML ordered list
- Copy links of all tabs in all windows as HTML unordered list
- Copy links of all tabs in all windows as Markdown ordered list
- Copy links of all tabs in all windows as Markdown unordered list

Comment: It's great, thanks! But what if I only want use `Copy link of active tab in current window as Markdown`? Could you add a default setting, if it set, the press of `Copy Tab info` icon not show dropdown, but do what the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the menu item **"More tools" - "Save page as..." (or Ctrl + S)**.
- When "Save As" dialog box is displayed:

  - Delete ".html" suffix from the text in "File name" text box
  - Copy the text from "File name" text box (which should be the page title).
  - Cancel "Save As" dialog box

["Save As" dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HcZW.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner that works for me on Chrome (compared to other solutions here)

```
javascript:(function(){var t=document.title,e=window.location.href,n=document.createElement("a");n.setAttribute("href",e),n.innerText=t,document.body.appendChild(n);var r=document.createRange(),o=window.getSelection();r.selectNode(n),o.removeAllRanges(),o.addRange(r),document.execCommand("copy"),document.body.removeChild(n)})();
```

So tabs get copied as: [Google](https://www.google.com)

In summary, the code creates a temporary  element with the title and URL of the current page, adds it to the document body, selects the element's content, copies it to the clipboard, and then removes the temporary element. This allows you to copy a clickable hyperlink to the clipboard, which you can paste into other applications.

This is the exact same functionality as in Edge, when copying URLs.

Answer (score 0):

### Drag page icon to the bookmarks toolbar

One simple way that doesn't require any extras is to drag the small icon  to the left of the URL to the Bookmarks bar (use CTR+Shift+B or Command+Shift+B to show/hide it), and then right-click on the new bookmark, pick **Edit** and copy the title.

[image]

### Drag page icon to folder or the desktop

You can also drag the icon to a folder or to your desktop. On most systems this will create a bookmark file and set the page title as file name, from where it can be easily copied.

### Drag page icon directly into a rich text document window

If you drag the page icon into Pages, Word, LibreOffice, Notes, etc on OSX this will insert a link with the page title as text and the URL as link target. On Windows and Linux just the plain text URL will be inserted, so it is not as handy, but can still be useful.

For example, the page icon from this SO page can be dragged directly into the reply edit form. Selecting the URL in the address bar and dragging it to an editable field usually has the same effect, and this is the alternative on OSX for example when you want the actual URL to be inserted instead of the linked title in a richtext edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bookmarklet that copies the title + url in markdown format

```
javascript:var title=document.title;if(title){var re= /(\\|\/|:|\*|\?|\"|<|>|\|)/gi;title="[" + title.replace(re,%27%27) + "]("+ document.location   + ")";void(prompt(%27Page Title%27, title));}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for it. [Copy URL To Clipboard - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url-to-clipboard/miancenhdlkbmjmhlginhaaepbdnlllc/related?hl=en-US)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, @Community. You are mistaken. The answer is sufficient. Shoo, be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the javascript mentioned by bugz above 
( `javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.title);` )

... use the following one in order to preserve the URL in the address field:

```
javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.title);history.replaceState({},"",location.href);
```

Source: [topic/47747/copy-page-title | Vivaldi Forum](https://forum.vivaldi.net/post/553446)